# Using memcpy to improve performance of random insertion in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I know that arrays provide constant time access to any of it's elements but to insert or remove element from start or in middle requires shifting of subsequent element and sometime resizing and copying of entire array. This can give linear complexity in worst scenario.

Can we make random insertion in array more efficient by using memcpy as shown in below example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int arr[16] = {0};
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
    {
        arr[i] = 1;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "INPUT ARR:";
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;


    std::memcpy(arr+9,arr+8,sizeof(int)*2); arr[8] = 9;// std::cout << std::endl << "NO " << *(arr+8);
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since memcpy is implemented directly in hardware using DMA without any CPU interference this approach can speed up insertion or removal at random position in array. Am I wrong here ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Why do you believe that the normal reallocation, that occurs when an array's contents are inserted or removed, is not already implemented with a `memcpy`, or an equivalent, in the C++ library? Rule #1 when working with C++: you are not smarter than the C++ library.

Comment: I was thinking that in array elements are placed one after the another sequentially in memory that's why to access 8th element in array is constant time because CPU just have to load arr+8. Now if I want to insert element before 8 and increase length of that array by 1 then I will have to move 8th element to 9th, 9th to 10th and then change 8th element. Are you trying to say that compiler will implicitly call memcpy here?

Comment: The code shown has a bug: `memcpy` requires non overlapping memory areas. Use `memmove`, here.

Comment: When in doubt, benchmark! Compare your code against the standard library's `std::vector` container. That way you'll know which one is faster.

Comment: Well, when you insert a new element in a middle of a `std::vector`, the process by which the remaining elements get shifted over, to make room for the new element, it doesn't happen by magic.

Answer (score 5):

> Since memcpy is implemented directly in hardware using DMA without any CPU interference

This is not true, at least on modern x86 CPUs. See [x86-64 GNU libc memcpy implementation](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/glibc/master/view/head:/sysdeps/x86_64/memcpy.S).

And another note is that `memcpy` cannot be used on overlapping memory regions. `memmove` needs to be used for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to old/obsolete information, in characterising `memcpy()` as implemented directly in hardware using DMA without CPU interference.

Your example also uses `memcpy()` with overlapping regions of memory (source and destination have some part in common).   That results in undefined behaviour.    The assumption of no overlaps is part of the reason that `memcpy()` can often be optimised more aggressively than (say) `memmove()` (which does the same thing, but allows the memory areas to overlap).

Anyway, in practice, a compiler is probably able to assign array elements reasonably efficiently.    For larger copying operations, `std::copy()` will often be reasonably efficient as well - such as using `memcpy()` - or some other optimisation technique - as well.

Without testing, to determine whether there is any need to optimise for speed or (if it is necessary) to identify the performance hotspots, all you are doing is premature optimisation.    A test case which only copies a small number of integers within an array - even if it doesn't involve undefined behaviour - is hardly a sufficient test case.

Comment: I am working on exchange software which requires queing data without any CPU delay. Linked list was my choice as I can insert data anywhere withing constant time whereas in array I have to do shifting of elements. Since array provides good constant time access I want to use it and thinking of using memcpy or memmove to get rid of cpu hog when I am shifting array elements.

Comment: @noname: Keep in mind that for small arrays, linear time can be better than the constant time insertion offered by linked lists. In particular, you often have the problem that finding the insertion point in a linked list is O(n), so you don't actually benefit from a single O(1) insertion. You often need multiple O(1) insertions close together to make the linked list insertion efficient. (Another case is with insertions near the beginning, but then `std::deque` might be even more appropriate)